# How to install composer for portable

Tags: php, git, github, web, composer-php

I have a repository with a bunch of code in it and a composer.json and a composer.lock.

When I want to run the website on a different server I have so clone the repo and then run `composer install` in the root of the repo.

However I want to be able to download the repo put it on a server and it should just work, without having to execute anything.

Even if I included the vendor folder in the repo and then try to put that on a webserver it gives me errors like "bla bla require() failed in some php file in vendor folder".

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all that's not bla bla, respect errors. Second what you looking for is called automated deployment. Tools like flightplan, chef and puppets are used for these things. Third you never put vendor folder in VCS.

Comment: Do you have `composer.lock` in your repo? If don't, composer will download the newest versions of packages, if you have any wildcards in `require`. That may make a difference.

Comment: But i don't want to have to execute anything. I just want to be able to upload the files I have in the repo through ftp or something onto a webserver and  it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A deployment of an application using Composer usually goes like this:

1. Checkout the appropriate version of the application from Git. You could also run `git archive` and pipe the result into `tar` to create a version that does not have the `.git` folder.
2. Run `composer install`
3. Transfer the created folder structure onto the target system.

All in all you'd probably only copy everything you already have on your development machine to the new system.

If that does not work, you have to be more specific with your error message.